# /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Workflow.svc/GetListActivityInstances failed to execute

Tags: core-service, cme, infrastructure

I received read-only access to a client's Tridion CM and noticed that messages started popping up in the Message Center:

> /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Workflow.svc/GetListActivityInstances
>   failed to execute.

[image]

This message popups up a every few seconds, so my Message Center queue is filled up with over 600 messages now.

I don't have access to anything back-end - only read-only CME.  So unfortunately, the best I could do at the moment is Google search this error.  This Q&A seems to be due to a similar : [/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings taking TEN minutes to respond](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/webui-models-tcm54-services-general-svc-getusersettings-taking-ten-minutes-to-r), but I'm not sure.

If anyone has encountered this in the past it would be helpful to have the answer here for others.  Please share.

Answer (score 2):

In 2011 service urls containing /tcm54/ referenced older COM+ functionality so I would typically first take a look there. 2013 doesn't use COM+ anymore, but I'm not sure if an upgraded 2013 machine may still use it.

If you look at the response from the url (using firebug or similar) do you see a more detailed error?  like a core service failing?

Comment: That does make it sound like a somewhat incomplete upgrade: 2013 is not supposed to use any 5.4 code anymore

Comment: I think you are not right, Nuno.
It's UI error...And UI models, which were introduced in 5.4, etc. They have new realization but old name.
Btw - I've seen this exception in 7.0 / 7.1.
Can't remember exactly, but probably it occurs when you have problem with connection to CoreService.
To find source of the problem - I'll advice to look to event log/fiddler/traces, to understand firstly where the
problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same error message, and taking the advice from Syav4eg above, this is what I found in my **Application** Windows event log.  The message is self-explanatory, my system was running low on memory, plus it gives both a solution and a workaround (see below).  There may be more than one reason for the original message, but here's hoping this helps.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/63835064
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Workflow.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (312438784 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.. ---> System.InsufficientMemoryException: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (312438784 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceMemoryGates.Check(Int32 minFreeMemoryPercentage)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 38908
```