# How to Properly Dispose TopologyManagerClient?

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager, c#

We are using the `Tridion.TopologyManager.Client` assembly in our custom C# application to interact with the Topology Manager items. When I look at the assembly (version 8.5.0.466), I don't see any methods that will dispose the TopologyManagerClient. The class doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface.

[image]

So my questions are

- Do I have to explicitly close the client so it can be garbage collected?
- If so how do I properly dispose the TopologyManagerClient so it doesn't take up resources?

Comment: you can wrap your code inside using(){  } block which should dispose the client automatically.

Comment: You cannot wrap a class in using if it doesn't implement `IDisposable` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392508/using-statement-in-c-sharp-without-implementing-dispose-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general all objects having any interaction with unmanaged resources should be disposed. With the `CoreServiceClient` (CS client) it's obvious and easy to do (see [Tridion 2013 SP1 Core service timeout with frequent requests](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19581/tridion-2013-sp1-core-service-timeout-with-frequent-requests/19582)), however with the `TopologyManagerClient` (TP client) it's not that straightforward. One difference is that the CS client is a "pure" WCF client which inherits from `ClientBase` which implements the `IDisposable` (see below),

```
public class SessionAwareCoreServiceClient : ClientBase<ISessionAwareCoreService>, ISessionAwareCoreService 
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable where TChannel : class
```

while the TP client is an OData (and not WCF) client which does not implement `IDisposable`

```
public class TopologyManagerClient : Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext
```

Technically speaking, saying that OData has no connection with WCF is incorrect:

> OData Service using WCF Service. OData is a standardized protocol for creating and consuming data APIs. OData builds on core protocols like HTTP and commonly accepted methodologies like REST

So, having all this in mind, the question of disposing the TP client and how to do it should be approached from that direction, ie. *should I, and if yes, how should I dispose an **OData** client*, but if IIRC, you needn't.

Comment: Good answer, but the quote about OData and WCF is a bit confusing. Indeed, it is possible to create a OData *Service* using WCF Data Services, but note that the Topology Manager Sevice is not implemented using WCF either (bur using WebAPI).  Regardless, this is separate from the client (which is largely auto-generated based on the Service metadata).